# realization of qsort using random pivot C

Tags: c, qsort

My qsort using random pivot is too slow, so it can't pass all tests. Qsort with middle element as pivot is also too slow (because of special test). How can I improve my qsort? I don't really know what's wrong with it.

Comment: This is better suited at https://codereview.stackexchange.com/

Comment: Try choosing the median of the first, middle and last element as pivot

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here are some suggestions:

- only call `srand(time(NULL));` once in the `main()` function, not in the `randompartition` function.
- use the same type `int32_t` for the array and the input/output methods. This will let you use a single call to `fread` and `fwrite` to load and store the data.  Note however that this approach is non portable: it will fail if the file was produced with a different endianness.
- the random pivot is not fully random: the last element will never be chosen because `right` is the offset of the last element, not the offset of the element past the end of the array. This convention is error prone and leads to confusing +1/-1 adjustments and off by one errors such as this one.
- The pathological case for this approach is a array with all identical elements. You might want to handle this case by computing the slice of identical elements around `p` and only recurse on smaller slices at the left and right of these elements.